# Is it possible to send stackExchange questions/answers to ReadItLater, or to browse them when offline from a smartphone?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I frequently stumble upon interesting questions and answers during the day, but don't have time to read them during work.  I've setup readItLater with my smartphone, for offline browsing, and synced this with my kindle for reading at the gym, which works great for almost all other posts I stumble upon during the day.  However, the text view for StackExchange sites on RIL is broken, in that posts aren't formatted as an article, and the RIL parser breaks down and can't display text.  This is fair enough, and could be a basic constraint of their system, which would be understandable, but I wonder, has anyone figured out a way to save and later read stackExchange sites from some type of offline reading service?

Comment: Or you star questions so you can browse them in your favorites later on? Plus you might want to check StackApps.com, it hosts all the apps people have made with our API

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any ReadItLater related topics on StackApps, our site for applications that interact with Stack Exchange.

As Ivo mentioned, using favourites is easy. Simply navigate to your profile and hit [**Favourites**](https://superuser.com/users/58299/nathan?tab=favorites). Stack Exchange mobile even supports you favouriting, and will load perfectly. I frequent it using an iPod Touch. You can look over on this page to see [which browsers are officially supported by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) - there is no guarantee your mobile browser will function.

Answer (score 2):

Use Instapaper instead, it can handle Stack Exchange sites without issue.

There is a Stack App called [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/), which creates a "printable view" of a question and its answers. This might work for you as well.

Comment: Not sure I'll finish it over the weekend since I have to do some other stuff, but it should be useable, although not convenient, in its current form at http://ReadStackLater.beckweb.net/ . Feedback (understanding the unpolished state) is always welcome.